# Cannot install geonode in window

Tags: python, django, gis

i am getting the following error when i run the command pip install -e geonode. I am in the process of installing geonode. I am using window 10.

```
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'C:\Users\eidulameen.sh\Documents\geonode_env\Scripts\python.exe' -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\\Users\\eidulameen.sh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wk7ukb8e\\uwsgi_17dc79202ede4643a13c8c5233dc91cc\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'C:\\Users\\eidulameen.sh\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-wk7ukb8e\\uwsgi_17dc79202ede4643a13c8c5233dc91cc\\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base 'C:\Users\eidulameen.sh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-pip-egg-info-71v4l6zx'
         cwd: C:\Users\eidulameen.sh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wk7ukb8e\uwsgi_17dc79202ede4643a13c8c5233dc91cc\
    Complete output (7 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "C:\Users\eidulameen.sh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wk7ukb8e\uwsgi_17dc79202ede4643a13c8c5233dc91cc\setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        import uwsgiconfig as uc
      File "C:\Users\eidulameen.sh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-wk7ukb8e\uwsgi_17dc79202ede4643a13c8c5233dc91cc\uwsgiconfig.py", line 8, in <module>
        uwsgi_os = os.uname()[0]
    AttributeError: module 'os' has no attribute 'uname'
    ----------------------------------------
WARNING: Discarding https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/c7/75/45234f7b441c59b1eefd31ba3d1041a7e3c89602af24488e2a22e11e7259/uWSGI-2.0.19.1.tar.gz#sha256=faa85e053c0b1be4d5585b0858d3a511d2cd10201802e8676060fd0a109e5869 (from https://pypi.org/simple/uwsgi/). Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement uWSGI==2.0.19.1 (from geonode)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for uWSGI==2.0.19.1
```

Any ideas how to solve the issue. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is related to these production and tests packages in [requirements.txt](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/3.3.1.post1/requirements.txt#L141-L166) and  [setup.cfg](https://github.com/GeoNode/geonode/blob/3.3.1.post1/setup.cfg#L167-L192) as they should run in a Linux environment not Windows.

If you try to comment them, the issue will not appear.

Also, you may try the [Cartoview Windows Installer](https://cartoview.net/). Cartoview is an extension of GeoNode visualizing the layers and maps in geospatial apps.